# Continuous Intergration Build configuration with seconds

Tags: jenkins

Is there any option there to configure build for project in seconds.

I tried with `*/0.2 * * * *`

Comment: As someone who oversees Jenkins implementations for hundreds of applications with thousands of jobs, I've seen some pretty strange use cases, but never one that needs to run every few seconds. What would need ro run that often? Is there a better way or tool to implement what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, just because that is how cron works.
If you want something faster, don't use cron.
Simply have a single job that runs infinitely, and have your code sleep .2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Least you can run a cron is for every minute. There's is no way you can run cron every 2 sec except a shell script or putting sleep in cron which might be of no help in Jenkins if you are looking for building something periodically.

First way as pointed out by @grayaii :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  # Do something
  sleep 2;
done
```

Second Way is :

```
* * * * * (sleep 5 && <path-to-script>) &
```